# VB.Net Code exits routine on false if statement without executing 'Else' command

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I'm using the following code to connect to an Access database and check if user's names are added to a table, if they are, then depending on which table they belong to directly affects their access levels to the software.

```
Public Sub Check_Database_For_Access_Level(Name As String)


    Dim myCon = New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.Database_Connection_String)
    myCon.Open()
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader


    Dim Str

    Str = "SELECT * FROM [Admin] WHERE [Emp Name]=?"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(Str, myCon)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Emp Name", Name)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    dr.Read()

    If dr("Emp Name").ToString = Name Then 'ERROR HERE
        My.Settings.Setting_AccessLevel = "Administrator"
    Else
        Str = "SELECT * FROM [ReadWrite] WHERE [Emp Name]=?"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Emp Name", Name)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()

        If dr("Emp Name").ToString = Name Then
            My.Settings.Setting_AccessLevel = "Read And Write"
        Else

        End If

    End If



    myCon.Close()
End Sub
```

The line:

```
If dr("Emp Name").ToString = Name Then 'ERROR HERE
```

operates as it is supposed to if the result is true, but if it is false, the sub simply exits?

How come it isn't firing the `Else` part? Even stepping through it simply exits.

Comment: There's an exception being quietly swallowed here (my guess is your method is being called from your main form's `Load` event handler or similar). Put a `Try/Catch` around the call to `Check_Database_For_Access_Level` and see what it is.

Comment: Perhaps it's throwing an exception - likely to be a `NullReferenceException` because I'm guessing `dr("Emp Name")` will be null if the user isn't in the admin table, which means you can't call `.ToString` on it, so it errors.  Try `If dr("Emp Name") IsNot Nothing AndAlso dr("Emp Name").ToString() = Name Then`

Comment: `myCon.Close()` should be placed in a finally block

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I should have thought about the old try catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM...` and use `ExecuteScalar`, as then a return value is pretty much guaranteed. Your intended check of the second table won't work because you haven't changed the `.CommandText`:

```
Using myCon As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.Database_Connection_String)

    myCon.Open()

    Dim sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Admin] WHERE [Emp Name]=?"

    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, myCon)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Emp Name", name)
        Dim n = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

        If n = 1 Then
            My.Settings.Setting_AccessLevel = "Administrator"
        Else
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [ReadWrite] WHERE [Emp Name]=?"
            n = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

            If n = 1 Then
                My.Settings.Setting_AccessLevel = "Read And Write"
            Else
                ' no such user OR more than one user with the same name
            End If

        End If

    End Using

End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

You SQL Statement contains a WHERE clause that already checks if the name passed as parameter is present or not in the database. So you don't really need to check again that condition. You could simply count how many records are present with that name and using a simpler ExecuteScalar to find out if you have at least one record with that name

```
Str = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Admin] WHERE [Emp Name]=?"
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(Str, myCon)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Emp Name", Name)
dim result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
if result > 0 Then
   ' You have the Admin with that name
else
   ' Check the other table
End If
```

Notice also that executing a COUNT is generally considered a bad method to accomplish this work but I am pretty sure that Access doesn't support more advanced techniques available in SQL Server and other database systems (IF EXISTS....)

Comment: Thanks, didn't even think I'd already checked the name exists